# How to save file and click ok from download dialog box using RSelenium?

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=0&amp;filetype=model_bz2'>Download all Models for all Coefficients</a>
```

With this code, I tried to download the file

```
library(RSelenium)
webpage <- "https://cluspro.bu.edu/models.php?job=705945"
browser <- remoteDriver(port = 5556)
browser$open()
browser$navigate(webpage)

clk <- browser$findElement(using = "link text", "Use the server without the benefits of your own account")
clk$clickElement()

  dnl_models <- browser$findElement(using = "link text", "Download all Models for all Coefficients")
dnl_models$clickElement()
```

Then it brings me to a dialog like this:

[image]

How can I save file and click ok with RSelenium?

---

This is the full HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <title>ClusPro 2.0: protein-protein docking</title>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/style.css' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/loginform.css' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/signupform.css' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/contactform.css' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/jobsform.css' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/goodform.css' />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/grids/grids-min.css" />
      <style type="text/css">#tabResults { font-weight:bold; }</style>      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
      
                     <script type="text/javascript">
                  
   var models = {
      reinit: function(){
         var showmodels = $('#showmodels').prop('value');
         $('td:gt('+showmodels+')').hide();
         $('td:eq('+showmodels+')').hide();
         $('td:lt('+showmodels+')').show();
         $('#modelslink').prop('href', 'zipmodels.php?job=705945&coeffi=0&nmodels='+showmodels);
      }
   }
$(document).ready(function(){
   models.reinit();
   $('#showmodels').change(models.reinit);
})
               </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="doc">
        <div id="hd">
          <ul id='tabs-menu'>
            <li><a id='tabContact' href='/contact.php'>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a id='tabHelp' href='/help.php'>Help</a></li>
            <li><a id='tabPapers' href='/publications.php'>Papers</a></li>
                        <li><a id='tabResults' href='/results.php'>Results</a></li>
            <li><a id='tabQueue' href='/queue.php'>Queue</a></li>
            <li><a id='tabDimer' href='/dimer_predict/submit.php'>Dimer Classification</a></li>
            <li><a id='tabPeptide' href='/peptide/index.php'>Peptide Docking</a></li>
            <li><a id='tabDock' href='/home.php'>Dock</a></li>
          </ul>
          <img src='/image/ClusPro1.png' width='750' height='160' alt=''/>
        </div>
    <div id="bd">
        
          
        <div id='main-header-right'>
          <a href='/logout.php'>sign out</a>
        </div>
       <h3><a href='jobdetail.php?job=705945'>Job Details</a>: lrp1_vs_Hx1sh2</h3><h4><a href='scores.php?job=705945&coeffi=0'>View Model Scores</a></h4><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=0&amp;filetype=model_bz2'>Download all Models for all Coefficients</a><div style="padding-top:1em;">Balanced | <a href='models.php?job=705945&amp;coeffi=2'>Electrostatic-favored</a> | <a href='models.php?job=705945&amp;coeffi=4'>Hydrophobic-favored</a> | <a href='models.php?job=705945&amp;coeffi=6'>VdW+Elec</a></div><br /><div>Display Models: <form style='display:inline;'><select id='showmodels'><option value='10'>10</option><option value='15'>15</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='23'>23</option></select></form></div><br /><a id='modelslink' href=''>Download Displayed Models</a><br /><br /><strong>If you use these models in a paper, please cite our <a href='publications.php'>papers</a></strong><br /><br /><table class='nice' id='models'><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=0&amp;filetype=model_file'>0</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=0&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='0' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=1&amp;filetype=model_file'>1</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=1&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='1' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=2&amp;filetype=model_file'>2</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=2&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='2' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=3&amp;filetype=model_file'>3</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=3&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='3' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=4&amp;filetype=model_file'>4</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=4&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='4' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=5&amp;filetype=model_file'>5</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=5&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='5' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=6&amp;filetype=model_file'>6</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=6&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='6' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=7&amp;filetype=model_file'>7</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=7&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='7' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=8&amp;filetype=model_file'>8</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=8&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='8' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=9&amp;filetype=model_file'>9</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=9&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='9' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=10&amp;filetype=model_file'>10</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=10&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='10' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=11&amp;filetype=model_file'>11</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=11&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='11' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=12&amp;filetype=model_file'>12</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=12&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='12' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=13&amp;filetype=model_file'>13</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=13&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='13' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=14&amp;filetype=model_file'>14</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=14&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='14' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=15&amp;filetype=model_file'>15</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=15&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='15' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=16&amp;filetype=model_file'>16</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=16&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='16' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=17&amp;filetype=model_file'>17</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=17&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='17' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=18&amp;filetype=model_file'>18</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=18&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='18' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=19&amp;filetype=model_file'>19</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=19&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='19' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=20&amp;filetype=model_file'>20</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=20&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='20' /></td><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=21&amp;filetype=model_file'>21</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=21&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='21' /></td></tr><tr><td><a href='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=22&amp;filetype=model_file'>22</a><br /><br /><img src='file.php?jobid=705945&amp;coeffi=0&amp;model=22&amp;filetype=model_img' alt='22' /></td><td>23<br /><br />(image not found)</td></tr></table>        </div>
        <div id="ft">
          ClusPro should only be used for noncommercial purposes.
          <br/>
          <a href='https://www.vajdalab.org' target='_blank'>Vajda Lab</a> and <a href='http://abcgroup.cluspro.org'>ABC Group</a>
          <br/>
          <a href='https://www.bu.edu/'>Boston University</a> and <a href='http://www.stonybrook.edu'>Stony Brook University</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I am  not familiar with R-Selenium, but if you are using firefox browser, then please use it with options. In options you will have to pass args. so that when automation window is launched  and when you make a click, it wouldn't open the download bar. I could give you solution in Python-Selenium.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66320754/6356278) of me can probably help you (using rselenium firefox)

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624770/automate-headless-firefox-in-rselenium-with-profile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574012/rselenium-setting-makefirefoxprofile-for-mac-os-x-to-download-files-without-ask

Comment: @Wimpel Thanks but the file I'm downloading is `bz2` format not `csv`.

Comment: @NadPat Thanks but the file I'm downloading is `bz2` format not `csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your existing setup, some of which you may already have, just shown here to illustrate, basically supressing the download popup, as well never asking to save for that mime type (bz2)

```
require(RSelenium)
dirdownload <- "/path_to/my_output_dir"
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = dirdownload,
                                 browser.download.folderList = 2L,
                                 browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "application/x-bzip2"))
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
```

Comment: It works, but when I added `browser.download.dir = "/path_to/my_output_dir/", browser.download.folderList = 2,` But it doesn't go to the desired saving dir above.

Comment: Updated my answer, based on your download issue - looks like old bug still may be around, try it out

Comment: I tried your update, still doesn't work. It goes to the default Mac's `Downloads` directory.

Comment: Are you running firefox on docker ? via docker desktop ?

Comment: No docker. I use `./geckodriver` and `java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -port 5556`

Comment: Can you try `browser.download.dir = "/path_to/my_output_dir"` - removed the trailing slash

Comment: Tried that too. No effect

Comment: Can you try this setting instead: `browser.download.folderList = 2L`

Comment: you saved my life AGAIN! I awarded you the bounty and edited your code to include 2L. Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome !!

Answer (score 1):

To download in the working directory, you can try,

```
library(stringr)
fold = str_replace_all(getwd(), '/', '\\\\')

fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = fold,
                                 browser.download.folderList = 2L,
                                 browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "application/x-bzip2"))
```